# Why LOSS is constantly increasing in tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I am using `faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco` model from the model zoo of tensorflow. I trained the model on my own data (solar images) and as I am observing the training (in tensorboard) the total loss is constantly increasing.
[image]

This is surprising to me because the model seems to be pretty successful in detecting the objects.

Comment: Could you give information about which layers you are freezing, and how many classes you are trying to predict?

Comment: As I mentioned, I am training the model on my own data, so no transfer learning is taking place here (that I am aware of, at least). About your other question, I am trying to "detect" (not predict) only one single object type.

Comment: The total loss is the validation loss. I met the same issue and I tried different learning rates. And if I increase the initial learning rate, the validation loss would drop.

Comment: I have the same issue. Would be nice to have an answer.